# Using StreamSocket in backgroundtask

Tags: sockets, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

A new feature in Windows 10 Universal apps is that you can transfer ownership (SocketStream.TransferOwnership) of a StreamSocket to the "socket broker" when the app is not running, and then react to socket activity through a Socket Activity Trigger.

There's a sample here https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket

However I'm having a hard time figuring whether this could be used in the scenario of for instance an IRC client on  Windows 10 mobile. It would seem the socket would have nearly constant activity and the trigger would only run occasionally? Ideally you'd want to use the "background socket" to log **all** socket activity when its not running in the foreground...

I haven't really been able to find much about this feature and the MSDN documentation is pretty sparse

Answer (score 1):

> > It would seem the socket would have nearly constant activity and the trigger would only run occasionally? Ideally you'd want to use the "background socket" to log all socket activity when it is not running in the foreground

When the socket ownership was transferred to background, the background task will be triggered when there are any socket activates. For example, new data was sent from the socket server or the socket was closed.

If you only want to background task to handle log the socket activities when the app is not running in the foreground, the app can take the ownership back though the code as following:

```
    SocketActivityInformation socketInformation;

    if (SocketActivityInformation.AllSockets.TryGetValue(SOCKET_ID, out socketInformation))
    {
        socket = socketInformation.StreamSocket;
    }
```

**App start: take the ownership back**

**App suspending: transfer the ownership**

**App resume: take the ownership back**

Please correct me if I have any misunderstandings on your question :)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thanks for your answer, and sorry for late reply!  So I guess the main thing I'm wondering is when the socket is transfered to the background task, how long will it be able run there? Typically tasks are forced closed if they're executing for too long, is this an exception?

Comment: No reply to OP :;/